# Htaccess redirects to index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

What's wrong with my htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Problem:

Sometimes for unknown reasons page:

```
domain.com/catalog/test
```

Redirect to

```
domain.com/index.php/catalog/test
```

I can add validation to PHP. But I want to solve the problem systematically. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: @Jeto Should I rewrite the line like this? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: @Jeto Absence " index.php " in URL

Comment: Yeah I actually misread your post, my bad. Ignore my previous comments, sorry about that!

Comment: @anubhava no, it's pretty virtual URL for routing

Comment: In that case, none of these rules are at fault. If you can reproduce this redirection then test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.